# Не могу сохранить файл с удаленной машины Linux

Tags: linux, ftp

При сохранении  с удаленной машины пишет 
ftp: //... is not a valid location. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

Использую  vsftpd. В конф файле 
local_enable=YES
write_enable = YES

Возможно нужно дать права доступа на файл? У меня консоль так что gedit не предлогать.

Comment: Ну вы бы привели сначала лог консоли, что ли :)

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko сервер на консоле проблем нет там, я с воркстейшн захожу под убунту с графикой и мне пишет ошибку когда я хочу сохранить файл. Может с правами доступа файла(папки) что-то?

Comment: А вы так и набираете `ftp: //`(с пробелом)?